# bootstrap theme navbar error fix

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i searched some themes of bootstrap and found this: [link](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-agency/#about)

when you open it, the navbar is white, but when you try to scroll, the color of the navbar (and its height) changes. i think this is an error. does anybody know how to fix it? i am not very familiar with bootstrap, because i work only since few hours with it.

i read about the `scrollspy` function of bootstrap, but i'm not sure if this is a javascript or css problem?

thank you

Comment: Not an error the dark image loads slow sometimes. Use a smaller image, jpg AND put a dark background behind the image on the img tag, this will disquise the load time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I didn't misunderstand you, what you're describing is not a Bootstrap error, but a "bug" in the navbar behavior. I'll try to explain.

That navbar is using [this Javascript code](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-agency/js/cbpAnimatedHeader.js) for changing its size and background color on scroll. It's almost the exact same code you can find in [this tutorial](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/06/on-scroll-animated-header/), which I guess was what the maker of the template used for the navbar.

The behavior you describe happens only if you load the page pointing to an anchor somewhere in the middle of the page. I mean, the link in your question is pointing to `http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-agency/#about`. But if I remove the `#about` part and refresh, then color doesn't flash and size doesn't change.

Why? The navbar is doing this: When page loads, it should be big and transparent, so the user can see the huge nice image behind it. And then, when the user scrolls a bit, it shrinks and gets a solid background.

But seems that the code, since it's a very simple one taken from a tutorial, doesn't take into account the case when the page is not being loaded from the top. So when you load it at the `#about` anchor, it's first rendered at its initial state (big and transparent) and then, when the javascript gets executed, it changes. This happens slow enough to be noticeable.

I'd say the `250` in the following code is what it's causing the visible delay. It's waiting for 250 milliseconds after the page is loaded and then adding or removing the class that triggers the navbar style change.

```
function init() {
    window.addEventListener( 'scroll', function( event ) {
        if( !didScroll ) {
            didScroll = true;
            setTimeout( scrollPage, 250 );
        }
    }, false );
}
```

**What you can do:**

As a quick solution, if you downloaded the template code, you could try changing that `250` to a `1`, though the navbar might still show a quick flash of the first state before switching to the second one, I'm not sure. Or, if you don't want an animated navbar, just remove the Javascript and edit the CSS as much as you want.

However, if you don't really need opening the page at a specific anchor, or if you don't mind having that quick navbar transition, then it's easier to just leave it as it is.

Comment: from where do yo have this code? is `scrollPage` an existing function? i dont want it to scroll up, only the navbar should be set correctly.

Comment: It's explained in my second paragraph. I just looked at what js code the template was using (with Chrome Dev Tools, Sources tab), and saw a js file (first link) named `cbpAnimatedHeader.js v1.0.0`. I googled that and found the tutorial (second link). And yes, `scrollPage` is a function, you can see what it does in any of those links.

Comment: By the way, [here's](http://i.imgur.com/mZ9r8qJ.png) where I found the code with Chrome Dev Tools. And please, next time try to elaborate more on your question, doing some research first or posting some code is usually very helpful for the people answering.

Comment: thanks a lot. when i set the same function to `window.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", ..., false);` it works even after reload